# authentication for angularjs - how to define default access level?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, express

I'm trying to implement client-side authentication for my angular app, and I ran into some issues trying to define the initial access level for the new-comers.

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../app')));

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        console.log('inside auth');

        var role = routingConfig.userRoles.public,
            username = '';

        if(req.user) {
            role = req.user.role;
            username = req.user.username;
        }

        res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify({
            'username': username,
            'role': role
        }));

        res.render('index');
    });
```

the code is from my express node server.js file

'role' is where I define the access level of the user (anonymous 'role' would not have access to pages that require logging in). I am trying to define the default 'role' for the people visiting the page for the first time, but it seems like I am not getting into app.get('/') because I cannot see the console log when I first load the page. My assumption is it is because I am serving up the static files before any authentication is happening, but I cannot come up with a way to get around that.

help me plz =)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the order of app.get and app.use you should be able to achieve what you want.
Remember to specify third argument in get method (next)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('inside auth');

    // put your logic here
    // once you're done call next so static pages could be served
    next()
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../app')));
```